# how do I get the lteq <= operator to work with tuples in Scala?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, tuples, partial-ordering

I am attempting to fix the following:

```
val temp1 = (3, "hello")
val temp2 = (2, "abcde")
temp1 <= temp2
```

which returns the error

```
<console>:24: error: value <= is not a member of (Int, String)
              temp1 <= temp2
                    ^
```

I've tried adding the following to my code:

```
implicit val tempOrdering = new Ordering[(Int, String)] {
  override def compare(a: (Int, String), b: (Int, String)): Int =
    {
    if      (a._1 < b._1) { -1 }
    else if (a._1 > b._1) { 1 }
    else if (a._2 < b._2) { -1 }
    else if (a._2 > b._2) { 1 }
    else 0
    }
  override def lteq(a: (Int, String), b: (Int, String)): Boolean = compare(a, b) <= 0
}

implicit val tempPartialOrdering = new PartialOrdering[(Int, String)] {
  override def tryCompare(a: (Int, String), b: (Int, String)): Option[Int] = {
    if      (a._1 < b._1) { Some(-1) }
    else if (a._1 > b._1) { Some(1) }
    else if (a._2 < b._2) { Some(-1) }
    else if (a._2 > b._2) { Some(1) }
    else Some(0)
  }
  override def lteq(x: (Int, String), y: (Int, String)) = {
    tryCompare(x, y).map(_ <= 0).getOrElse(false)
  }
}
```

and temp1 <= temp2 still does not work.

I am able to run commands such as

```
List(temp1, temp2).min
```

but not

```
min(temp1, temp2)
```

so it seems that scala is not seeing my declaration of ordering for (Int, String) tuples.

I can reference my declaration using

```
tempPartialOrdering.lteq(temp1, temp2)
```

and some of my coworkers have suggested making a new class just for (Int, String) tuples, but I find these solutions inelegant.  I would REALLY like to be able to use the plain old "<=" comparison operator!

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, that "<=" is still not a member of (Int, String)?  Is there a way to implicitly set this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
scala> import Ordering.Implicits._
import Ordering.Implicits._

scala> (2,3) <= (1,2)
res2: Boolean = false
```

Comment: This also works with my (Int, String) pair in my example -- thanks!

Comment: You may actually want a hybrid solution, though, in case the second value in the pair is the most significant one.  I tested that if I use my implicit tempOrdering code above and rewrite so that the second value is evaluated first, this holds.  But if you don't declare the ordering, the default will be first value as most significant

Answer (score 0):

Your coworkers are right. Create a custom Type (aka class). It's much more elegant than you're giving it credit for.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do the following. You can extend it as necessary to get extra functionality. It is clunky, but it gets the job done and allows you to come up with custom ordering.

```
implicit class stringIntTuple(a: (String, Int)) extends (String, Int)(a._1,a._2) {
  def <= (x: (String, Int)): Boolean = {
    this._2 <= x._2
  }
}

temp1 <= temp2
```